# How to open a hyperlink on the same page with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using this to open on a new window:

```
<div class="backbutton" OnClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.goesback.com')">Go back</div>
```

How to amend this if I want onclick to open a hyperlink on the same page?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the url to the `window.location.href`

so

```
<div class="backbutton" OnClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.goesback.com'">Go back</div>
```

But you should really just convert it to a regular link

```
<a class="backbutton" href="http://www.goesback.com">Go back</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property:

```
<div class="backbutton" OnClick="window.location.href='http://www.goesback.com'">
    Go back
</div>
```

Or just use a plain old `anchor` (probably your best option):

```
<a href="http://www.goesback.com">Go back</a>
```

**Note:** the `javascript:` prefix is not needed in the `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

`location.href='http://www.goesback.com'`

Though you might want to reconsider using `onclick` to trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="backbutton" OnClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.goesback.com'">Go back</div>
```

Comment: The `javascript:` prefix is not needed for `onclick` handlers. The code is not throwing any errors, because `javascript:` is being interpreted as a label.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple anchor tag?

```
<a href="[where you want to go]">Go There</a>
```

If you need to use JavaScript, the other answers - setting the `window.location` property - will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of window.open() is a string representing the name of the target window.

Set it to: "_self".

```
<div class="backbutton" OnClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.goesback.com','_self')">Go back</div>
```